What difference does cooling stuffing make, before roasting a bird?
I have a recipe for a stuffed roast pheasant, and it explicitly says to cook the stuffing first then:

Cool. When cold, stuff into the cavity of the pheasants.

What difference does that make?

I assume these are instructions for before you cook the bird?

To really determine the reason I would need the rest of the instructions.  The problem with roasting pheasant is usually that they are very lean, making them very easy to dry out.  I have ways around it, but all would be impeded by stuffing.

The cooling step is to mitigate the incubation of pathogens inside the bird.  It takes a long time for the center of a stuffed bird to reach the temperatures where pathogens cannot grow.  You don't want stuffing that is warm (the perfect temperature for pathogen growth) to be sitting inside your bird (a hospitable  environment for pathogens), as it passes through the danger zone on the way to being cooked. If the stuffing is cold, and the bird is cold, everything passes through the danger zone at relatively the same rate.  The result is a safely cooked product.
I've never cooked a stuffed pheasant, but this is the reason I do not stuff a turkey.  By the time the center of the bird and stuffing is at a safe temperature, the white meat is dried out...well-over cooked.

But wouldn't starting from cold mean that your stuffing spends even longer in the 'danger zone' than if it's already closer to the edge to get back into safe territory?  If it starts cold and you're cooking a larger bird,  you're more likely to never have the stuffing reach the safe temperature

See Kenji: https://www.seriouseats.com/herb-rubbed-roast-turkey-with-stuffing#mntl-sc-block_23-0

@Joe I think there are 2 more factors. One is that if you stuff by hand you don't want to burn yourself, so there's a temptation to handle it warm rather than hot, i.e. in the danger zone already. The second is that the stuffing gives up some heat to the meat, but not much because it hasn't got much. So the meat nearest the cavity gets warmed initially, long before oven heat can reach it

I've also stopped stuffing a bird for the same reason @moscafj, a turkey also cooks much faster if it isn't stuffed.

For what it's worth, my usual amateur practice is to just shove a few onions in the body cavity and call it good. Baked onions are a fine thing, they add flavor to the bird, and a whole onion is less likely to get contaminated than chopped/mixed stuffing. Turkey is a lot easier to cook if you ignore all the complications, given a modern oven that can hold temperature properly.

Sorry, but this 'everything passes through the danger zone at relatively the same rate' is just wrong, even for a relatively small bird like a pheasant. There is always a big temperature gradient from hot outside to much colder center of the bird+stuffing. The most at risk part for pathogens would be the inside of the meat. If you want that part to be in a warm temperature range for a short time, starting with warm stuffing would actually help you, not hinder you.

@quarague The inside of the meat isn't that at risk for pathogens, because it's on the inside. Unless the bird had an infection while it was alive, there's not a way for the pathogens to get there.

@wizzwizz4 OTOH the inside of the cavity is another surface - which is exposed to hot air if unstuffed

I quickly and mistakenly (I think) upvoted two comments saying the 'everything passes through the danger zone at relatively the same rate' part is wrong, and now can't undo it :-(  Thinking about it more carefully, I do think the answer's claim is correct... but it's subtle and seems to be attracting objections.  I wonder if more explanation could be added to make it clearer that it's correct.

I do not buy this.  Pheasants are so quick to roast as they tend to weigh only between 0.7 - 1.1 kg I find it hard to believe there is time for bacterial action to be significant during cooking.  If the instructions included stuffing the night before it would make sense.

@User65535 I'm guessing the instructions don't make any assumption about how long the wait is between stuffing and cooking?   In which case, yeah, we could say the instructions implicitly include the possibility of stuffing the night before.

@wizzwizz4 Considering what was inside the cavity (which, as ChrisH pointed out, is the bit to be concerned about), then the interior of the bird is definitely a potential point of contamination. Gut contents can contain a lot of pathogens, and yes, any skillful butcher should have done it cleanly, but mistakes happen.

@quarague A temperature gradient certainly means that things won't pass through the danger zone at the same time, but (beyond the outermost centimetre or so) doesn't mean particularly much variance in how long they spend in the danger zone… if your oven is properly hot. Yes, if your oven temp is too close to the danger zone, then there will be notable variance, since temperature transfer is non-linear across the differential. But this is also why things heat up faster if they start colder — e.g. hot water freezing faster than room-temperature water — and pass through the danger zone faster

It is hard to tell for sure, but there are a few possible explanations that come to my mind:

colder stuffing is easier to handle, as it can get "denser" as some of its compounds will be more solid/less liquid at lower temperatures
giving the stuffing time to cool, perhaps even a full night, helps with flavour blending/diffusion
it can also just be some mindless copy paste from a recipe that said that you can let it cool, e.g. prepare the stuffing in advance then preserve it in the fridge for up to x days, just for logistical reasons

At the end of the day, the best way to find out probably is try. I do not think this has much to do with food safety, as most normal people will let the stuffing cool to room temp, then refrigerate it, going slowly through the danger zone, then again through it after stuffing, during cooking of the bird. Time in the danger zone is cumulative, and stuffing the bird with hot stuffing will reduce the total time for any given part of the stuffing & the meat.
To be a bit more precise, thermal cycling the stuffing is less of a concern, as it usually is less "bad stuff" prone than the meat itself - still I would not leave it at room temperature for a prolonged period of time.
Starting the cooking process with hot stuffing is better than lukewarm stuffing, as with a bit of luck it will stay out of the danger zone 100% of the time, plus the bird will be ready earlier and it will be way more moist.
Note: a couple of commenters provided this useful link:
Easy Stuffed Roast Turkey With Giblet Gravy Recipe
In case it rots, I am including the key image:

[image credit: Serious Eats / J. Kenji Lopez-Alt]
The gist is that the higher you start, the more likely you are to never get into the danger zone. I believe that the data for the plot above was gathered with a single thermometer in the center of the stuffing; I expect the stuffing directly in contact with the fridge temperature bird to quickly cool down and possibly hit the danger zone (or below it!) depending on a number of factors/conditions.

"I do not think this has much to do with food safety, as most normal people will let the stuffing cool to room temp, then refrigerate it, going slowly through the danger zone, then again through it after stuffing," I'm not completely sure, but it sounds like you're talking about temperature of only the stuffing over time? My understanding is that's not really a concern, since the stuffing itself doesn't tend to cultivate dangerous pathogens. And then "stuffing the bird with hot stuffing will reduce the total time for any given part of the stuffing& the meat." Are you sure? (about the meat)

Yep I am referring to stuffing temperature only. Starting temperature of the stuffing is significant, as inside the bird it will be basted with bird juices, which are unsafe - admittedly I am imprecise about that. Regarding the third question - I am guessing a bit here, it is possible that depending on starting temperatures of all the food, thermal conductivity and son and so forth this might not be true. I expect it to be true in most if not all reasonable conditions. If you start with lukewarm stuffing it is most probably the worst possible condition.

"inside the bird it will be basted with bird juices, which are unsafe" -- ah, good point, thank you.  "If you start with lukewarm stuffing it is most probably the worst possible condition."  I think I agree with this.. however, if you put hot stuffing into the bird and then immediately put it all in the oven (or not), won't the hot stuffing, next to the cold turkey interior, almost immediately turn lukewarm, during the long period while the oven temperature more slowly heats the meat from the outside?  So that seems to fall into the case of "worst possible condition", not best, doesn't it?

(admittedly I'm thinking of turkey here, rather than pheasant)

@DonHatch Apparently fully hot stuffing doesn't ever go below the danger zone if stuffed  into a turkey and immediately roasted, according to Kenji Lopez-Alt

The problem here is that the reality of things depends on a big number of factors, difficult to control and/or measure. I am including the link in the answer as it is pretty informative.

"Stuffing" can also cover a lot of things - for example some is made with sausagemeat, i.e. pork
